# How to set continuous box-shadow through all inline-block centered li elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive layout so I center-positioned a horizontal CSS menu with:

```
ul {text-align: center;}    
ul li {display: inline-block;}
```

This way it stays vertically aligned on mobile device.

I would like to add a continuous box-shadow -> a shadow below the li buttons that would **stretch under all li** but not to the full menu width.

The problem is when I set it directly to:

```
ul li {box-shadow: 0px 8px 6px -6px yellow;}
```

The shadow is separated under each buttons (li elements).

---

When I set it to:

```
ul {box-shadow: 0px 8px 6px -6px yellow;}
```

The shadow is under the whole width of the menu, not just the place where the Li's are

---

How to put it just under the LI but continually under all of those? Maybe some wrapper element?

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/9B5SV/9/

Comment: and if you just drop your shadow of 2pixel without any blur effect : box-shadow: 0px 2px 0 0  yellow; http://jsfiddle.net/9B5SV/10/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Ft7DP/

```
<div id="menu"><ul><li>First</li><li>Second</li><li>Third</li></ul></div>
```

That's sorta the same stuff you had in your fiddle. Below is a simplified version of the CSS, the minimum amount to make it work as you requested:

```
#menu { text-align: center; }
ul { display: inline-block; box-shadow: 0px 8px 6px -6px yellow; }
li { display: inline-block; }
```

Make the whole UL an inline-block, this way it's width depends on it's contents instead of just going the whole way across. Now instead of putting text-align: center on the UL, put it on the div that's wrapping the UL. Then move the box-shadow from the LI to the UL and done :)

Answer (score -1):

Create a span tag that contains the li elements like this:

```
<ul><span id="licontainer"><li>First</li><li>Second</li><li>Third</li></span></ul>
```

And in the CSS:

```
#licontainer {box-shadow: 0px 8px 6px -6px yellow;};
```

Comment: The w3 specification says the only direct children of a UL can be an LI, it's not a good idea to put a span in there - not if you care about your HTML being valid, that is :P